# Discrete Time Fourier Transform of the signal represented by $x[n] = n^2 a^n u[n]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have a homework problem that I am just not sure where to start with.  I have to take the Discrete Time Fourier Transform of a signal represented by:

$$x[n] = n^2 a^n u[n]$$

given that $|a| < 1$,  $\Omega_0 < \pi$, and u[n] being the unit step function.

There is a hint saying that "Calculus and derivatives will help!" but that actually confuses me more than it helps.  However, regardless, I'm just not sure how to even get started evaluating that.  I know how to take the DTFT of a signal, but just can't figure out how to get it into a usable form.  I also am allowed to use the following conversion:

$$ x[n] = a^nu[n] \iff X(\Omega) = \frac{e^{j\Omega}}{e^{j\Omega} - a}$$

I am not looking for the answer, but rather just some pointers as to how to start manipulating the original signal.

Comment: I suppose $u$ is the unit step function? You should add its definition to the post. The hint probably means you should first solve the problem with $y[n] = a^n u[n]$ and then use the fact that multiplication by $n$ is related to taking derivative.

Comment: Good point, I updated it with that edit.  And I didn't think about it that way, I was trying to do the manipulation first, but nothing was coming out right.  But you make a good point that makes more sense now that I think about it more, I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: @Fundamental, your solution suggestion seemed to be the most helpful.  I completely forgot about the multiplication by n in the time domain being a derivative in the Fourier domain.  I would say this helped me the most and would have liked to have it marked as the answer.  But I know that the other answer posted would work as well

Comment: Sorry, don't have the time to write it out. Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: Oh alright, I wasn't meaning to post the actual answer to the question.  Just the method to try to go about solving it.  But I can post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include this as the answer that most helped me, since it was just as a comment to my original post.  The most straightforward solution seemed to be by using the property of the Discrete Time Fourier Transform for when you are multiplying by n in the time domain, that corresponds to a derivation in the Fourier/frequency domain.

Therefore, the solution would just be to take the Fourier transform from the provided conversion, and then taking the second derivative of that.  This is the solution that I got after doing so:

$$X(\Omega) = \frac{a^3e^{j\Omega} - ae^{j3\Omega}}{(e^{j\Omega} - a)^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given a definition for the discrete Fourier transform but I presume it is something like
$$X(\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(n) e^{-i\omega n}$$
which in this case would be
$$X(\omega) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2 a^n e^{-i\omega n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2 z^n$$
where $z = ae^{-i\omega}$.
Now suppose we set
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$$
This series converges provided that $|z| < 1$. Fortunately, we are given that $|z| = |a| < 1$. We can differentiate power series term by term in the interior of their disc of convergence, so
$$f'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nz^{n-1}$$
and
$$f''(z) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)z^{n-2} = z^{-2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)z^{n}$$
Try rearranging this to see if you can get an expression for $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^2 z^n$ in terms of $f'(z)$ and $f''(z)$. Then you can manually add the $n=0$ and $n=1$ terms.

You will also want to use the fact that
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$$
for $|z| < 1$.

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't provide that definition, but you have provided the correct one.  Alright I'll give that a shot as well.  Thanks

Comment: I can see where and how this would work out, but I think that the answer provided by Fundamental in the comments seems more straight forward.